# Flutter how to write java code in flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I have an application which runs correctly without any issue. I added Java code to it to use a method channel and the problem is that the application isn't able to run sound microphone camera and did not show me any authorization to accept using camera or sound.

The code which I added from Android works correctly and show me exactly what I want.

```
package com.example.akk;

import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;

//import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    private static final  String CHANNEL="samples.flutter.dev/battery";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
        new  MethodChannel(getFlutterView(),CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler(){
            @Override
            public void onMethodCall(MethodCall methodCall,MethodChannel.Result result ){
             if(methodCall.method.equals("getBatteryLevel")){
                 int batteryLevel = getBatteryLevel();

                 if (batteryLevel != -1) {
                     result.success(batteryLevel);
                 } else {
                     result.error("UNAVAILABLE", "Battery level not available.", null);
                 }
             } else {
                 result.notImplemented();
             }

             }

        });


    }
    private int getBatteryLevel() {
        // int health = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_HEALTH,0);


        int deviceHealth;
        int x=10;

        Intent intent = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext()).
                registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
        deviceHealth = (intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_HEALTH, 0));




        if(deviceHealth == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_DEAD){

            x=0;        }

        if (deviceHealth == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_GOOD){

            x=1;        }

        if(deviceHealth == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_OVERHEAT){

            x=2;        }

        if (deviceHealth == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_OVER_VOLTAGE){

            x=3;        }

        if (deviceHealth == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_UNKNOWN){

            x=4;        }
        if (deviceHealth == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_UNSPECIFIED_FAILURE){

            x=5;        }
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at the official documentation on this and let me know if this helps you: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels#example

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the code where you're having issues accessing camera and sound from the device. If you just need to provide camera and mic permissions, you can use the [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) plugin.

```dart
// Request camera and microphone permission
Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
  Permission.camera,
  Permission.microphone,
].request();
```